# Use which()-function with previous and following entries

Tags: r

Assume I have given a data in R containing three columns with (0,1)-entries:

```
c1 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0)
c2 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1)
c3 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0)

data <- data.frame(cbind(c1,c2,c3))
```

I want to identify the rows in c2 that have value 1 and where the previous row in c1 and the following row in c3 has also value 1.

So in principle something like this:

```
which(data$c2 == 1 & data$c1[previous] == 1 & data$c3[following] == 1)
```

In the example here it should give me 3. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead` and `lag` from `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

which(data$c2 == 1 & lag(data$c1) == 1 & lead(data$c3 == 1))
#> [1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a loop:

```
#Data
c1 <- c(0,1,0,0,1,0)
c2 <- c(0,0,1,0,0,1)
c3 <- c(0,1,0,1,0,0)
data <- data.frame(cbind(c1,c2,c3))
#Vector
rows <- c()
#Rows
vr <- c(2:(nrow(data)-1))
#Loop
for(i in 1:length(vr))
{
  if(data$c2[vr[i]]==1 & data$c1[vr[i]-1]==1 & data$c3[vr[i]+1]==1)
  {rows[i]<- vr[i]}
  rows <- rows[!is.na(rows)]
}
```

Output:

```
rows
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, you can do :

```
inds <- which(c(NA, head(data$c1, -1)) & data$c2 == 1 & c(tail(data$c3, -1), NA))
inds

#[1] 3
```